# xpath: how select radio button of particular item if html is equal and order could be changed

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

How can I click on radio button using xpath in selenium if I have following html:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" onclick="onSelect(this.form)" value="met" name="selected_item"/>
 </td>
 <td> Val1</td>
 <td> 1</td>
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" onclick="onSelect(this.form)" value="met" name="selecteditem"/>
 </td>
 <td> Val2</td>
 <td> 1</td>
```

**SOLUTION**
Finally I have found decision:

```
.//tr[td[contains(., 'Val1')]]/td[1]/input
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I tried this tr[(td[2] = ' Val1')]/td[1]/input

Answer (score 0):

```
//td[text()=' Val1']/preceding-sibling::td/input
```

or

```
//td[text()=' Val2']/preceding-sibling::td/input
```